# MIPS 5 stage basic

Tags: assembly, mips, pipeline

Question: Assume the following sequence of instructions is executed in a traditional 5-stage pipeline. Does the lw / add instruction combination represent a data hazard?  If so, why?  If not, why not?

```
lw  $5, 4($6)
sub $6, $5, $10
add $7, $6, $5
```

Comment: Why did you tag with [tag:networking] and [tag:element]? Anyway, yes, that is a hazard. Value of `$5` is not yet available when the `add` is executing.

Comment: I disagree. The `sub` instruction depends on the `lw` for the value of `$5`, but the `add` follows the `sub`, so the dependency on `$5` from the `lw` is not an issue. The `add` depends on `$6` from the `sub` instruction, though.

Comment: Depends on what is meant by "traditional" pipeline. Replacing the `sub` with something else would make the `add` a hazard. Just because the `sub` is also a hazard, doesn't invalidate the `add`. If you have mechanism in place to eliminate the hazard for the `sub` that will fix the `add` too, no question about that.

Comment: I still dont understand the question is lw/add combination represent a hazard or not?

Comment: If you ignore the `sub`, then it does. If you assume that the hazard created by `sub` is already handled, then no (with respect to `$5`).

Comment: Thanks a lot jester and what should I have tagged this with? Its a netowkring question isn;t it?